# Cocoa icon for file type?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

If I have a file, I can get the icon by doing something such as:

```
NSImage *iconImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile: @"myFile.png"];
```

But if I just wanted to get the icon for a specific file type (example the icon associated with png files, without having a "myFile.png" that already exists), i'm not sure how I can do that.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Underneath `-[NSWorkspace iconForFile:]` in the documentation is [`-[NSWorkspace iconForFileType:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-iconForFileType_).  Have you tried that?

Comment: Ha, no I missed that completely. Thanks for point that out to me.

Comment: Swift example: `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().iconForFileType("txt")`

Comment: Unfortunately determining the file's UTI and then producing a generic icon will not necessarily give the same result as iconForFile (Cocoa). For example, if I paste a custom icon on a folder or file in the Finder's Get Info pane, iconForFile will use that, whereas the newer Swift methods will not.

Answer (score 4):

You can first determine file type (UTI) and then pass it on to get icon:

```
NSString *fileName = @"lemur.jpg"; // generic path to some file
CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef)[fileName pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]iconForFileType:(__bridge NSString *)fileUTI];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Swift 5** version of [Dave DeLong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507927/3939277):

> ## [icon(forFile:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1528158-icon)
>
> Returns an image containing the icon for the specified file.
>
> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func icon(forFile fullPath: String) -> NSImage
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **`fullPath`**
>
> The full path to the file.

> ## [icon(forFileType:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1527879-icon)
>
> Returns an image containing the icon for files of the specified type.
>
> ### Declaration
>
> ```
> func icon(forFileType fileType: String) -> NSImage
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **`fileType`**
>
> The file type, which may be either a filename extension, an encoded HFS file type, or a universal type identifier (UTI).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! If you think my answer isn't useful, I'd love to hear more about how you think I could have written a more useful answer. Please leave a comment to help me improve!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **Swift 5** version of [PetrV's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32143483/3939277):

```swift
public extension NSWorkspace {

    /// Returns an image containing the icon for files of the same type as the file at the specified path.
    ///
    /// - Parameter filePath: The full path to the file.
    /// - Returns: The icon associated with files of the same type as the file at the given path.
    func icon(forFileTypeAtSamplePath filePath: String) -> NSImage? {
        let fileExtension = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath).pathExtension
        guard
            let unmanagedFileUti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension,
                                                                         fileExtension as CFString, nil),
            let fileUti = unmanagedFileUti.takeRetainedValue() as String?
            else {
                assertionFailure("Should've gotten a UTI for \(fileExtension)")
                return nil
        }

        return NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFileType: fileUti)
    }
}
```