# MacOS Get default application for file type

Tags: macos

I am working on a Mac app.  I ultimately want to use default app icons within my app.  From the Info.plist and the Resource folder of an app I can get the .icns file and convert that to the image format I need.  But I need to know the default application associated with the particular file extension, if any.

So how to get the default application that the system currently associates with a given file extension?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa icon for file type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507917/cocoa-icon-for-file-type)

Answer (score 2):

Don't go digging in other apps' bundles. It's always best to work at the level of abstraction that suits the question you want to ask. If you want to get the icon that the Finder (or a Mail attachment, etc) would display for a file of a particular type, use the `NSWorkspace` [`iconForFileType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/iconForFileType:) method.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is part of the OSX Launch Services: [LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForContentType) API. This returns the info on apps that can open specific [Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html). There's also a similar API called [LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/LSCopyDefaultApplicationURLForURL) to check which app opens a specific known file.

Comment: These are deprecated. Any idea how to do it now?

Answer (score 1):

## 2024

```
NSWorkspace.shared.urlsForApplications(toOpen: url)
```